# Sequences and Series of Function; equicontinuous

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Good evening! can anyone help me with this issue?

$(f_{n})$ sequence of functions equicontinuous and pointwise bounded on compact $X \subset \mathbb{R}$. If every subsequence uniformly convergent on X 
it has the same limit $f:X\longrightarrow\mathbb{R} $. 
Then$f_{n}\longrightarrow f$ converge uniformly on $X$.

Thanks

Comment: Something seems amiss.  $(f_{n})$ is its own subsequence, so how can it fail to converge to $f$ uniformly on $X$ when we are told that *every* subsequence does?

Comment: @avs You missed the "every subsequence *uniformly convergent*" (pretty clumsy English in th eOP, though: there is a duplication of the subject afterwards).

Comment: @G.Sassatelli, true. Communication is key.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an application of the Ascoli's theorem applied to $(f_n)$. You deduce that the sequence $(f_n)$ is relatively compact since it is equicontinue and for every $x\in X$, $\{f_n(x),c\in X\}$ is bounded.

Suppose that $(f_n)$ does not converges towards $f$, there exists $c>0$ a subsequence $(f_{n_i})$ such that $\|f_{n_i}-f\|>c$, but since $(f_n)$ is relatively compact, you can extract a subsequence $(f_{n'_i})$ from $f_{n_i}$ which converges, by hypothesis the limit as to be $f$. Contradiction.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem